# Database structure for job experience with varying requirements based on job selected

Tags: mysql, database, structure

EDIT: I'm asking for how to save the requirements and not the response from the users

I'm working on a job board, and when registering you can select your abilities like backend, frontend, design, etc...
On the next step, you need to fill out the experience you have in that particular field of job. This is where I'm stuck at on how to save these requirements in the database?

Example: 
If you select Backend:

```
- Backend
  Programming Languages
  Database Experience
  Server Experience
```

If you select Frontend:

```
- Frontend
  Frameworks
  Responsive and Mobile Design
  Preprocessors
```

Should I create a table with requierments for each type of job or save them all in one and link them with an id?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based or to broad to answer so most likely it will be voteclosed.. I suggest you given more details or a better user case and edit your question.